# What happens when two equal foreign keys with conflicting on-deletes are defined on the same table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

In order to delete some rows referenced by a foreign key constraint without cascading on delete, I created a temporary foreign key constraint, deleted the row, and then deleted the temporary constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE rel_user_right
  ADD CONSTRAINT temp_fk_rel_user_right_user_right_02
    FOREIGN KEY (right_id) REFERENCES user_right (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE;

DELETE FROM user_right WHERE "name" LIKE '%.statusLight.%';

ALTER TABLE rel_user_right
  DROP CONSTRAINT temp_fk_rel_user_right_user_right_02;
```

where this table already had the following constraint defined on it:

```
ALTER TABLE rel_user_right
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_rel_user_right_user_right_02
    FOREIGN KEY (right_id) REFERENCES user_right (id);
```

This worked fine for me, but seems to have failed on my colleague's computer. As you can see, the two FK constraints define conflicting `ON DELETE` behaviour. Is precedence defined in this situation, or is it non-deterministic?

Answer (score 2):

Postgres allows to create two references differing only in `ON DELETE` clause. 
I could find no information on the impact of such a case.

In my tests I was unable to *cover* the existing constraint with new one (i.e. `DELETE` was always restricted despite of the existence of the second *cascading* constraint).
However this behaviour is undocumented and one should not rely on it.

The *normal* way to proceed should be replacing the old constraint with new one:

```
ALTER TABLE rel_user_right
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_rel_user_right_user_right_temp
    FOREIGN KEY (right_id) REFERENCES user_right (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
  DROP CONSTRAINT fk_rel_user_right_user_right;

DELETE FROM user_right WHERE "name" LIKE '%.statusLight.%';

ALTER TABLE rel_user_right
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_rel_user_right_user_right
    FOREIGN KEY (right_id) REFERENCES user_right (id),
  DROP CONSTRAINT fk_rel_user_right_user_right_temp;
```

`DISABLE CONSTRAINT` would be useful here, but there is no such feature in Postgres (there have been attempts to [implement it](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/346433adf2d0bd1056c201cb5f372e49@highgo.com.cn), but they did not end in success). You can use `DISABLE TRIGGER` for it, but the above solution is simpler and more natural.

Comment: I think the outcome you see is logical. If both constraints fire, then either way the tx is aborted with an ERROR. In one case you might do an expensive cascade-delete first, but the tx that did it gets aborted, so it has no effect. Really, this seems like a "just don't do that" problem.

Comment: Thanks. I used a similar solution, but I added a second constraint first, then deleted the old one - just so that there's no time window during which the table doesn't have a constraint.

Comment: @CraigRinger - My intuition tells exactly the same.

Comment: @Zoltán - You're right. And this is the reason why this possibility is allowed. I'll update the answer so as not to confuse future readers. Thanks for the mention.